# Renaming Foreign Key for Value Object's Entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have column naming issue when using entities inside of a Value Object with Entity Framework Core. EF wants to name the foreign key of the value object's entity to a long ugly name. E.g. PropertyName_ForeignKeyID. What I want is to control the name of the db column field with Fluent API.

If I have a Value Object called Measurement and it has a property to an Entity called UnitOfMeasure, the relationships work just fine but the column naming is super ugly.

Following is the sample model

```cs
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Measurement VO { get; set; }
}

public class Measurement
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure UOM { get; set; }
}

// Second Entity
public class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and configuration I've tried

```cs
var withEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().OwnsOne(t => t.VO);

// This works fine
withEntity.Property(e => e.Value).HasColumnName("WithEntityValue");

// Tried this but the results of the column name is VO_WithEntityValueUOMId
withEntity.HasOne(e => e.UOM).WithMany().HasForeignKey("WithEntityValueUOMId");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasForeignKey` specifies the (shadow) *property* name. The conventional column name is the same as the property name, however for owned entity types it includes the owner property name (similar to other properties).

Hence what you need is to specify the *column* name similar to the "working" example. e.g. knowing that the conventional shadow FK *property* name in this case is `UOMId`, it could be set as follows

```cs
withEntity.Property("UOMId").HasColumnName("WithEntityValueOUMId");
```

or you can change both FK property and column names

```cs
withEntity.HasOne(e => e.UOM).WithMany().HasForeignKey("WithEntityValueUOMId");
withEntity.Property("WithEntityValueUOMId").HasColumnName("WithEntityValueUOMId");
```

In both cases, you need `Property(FKPropertyName).HasColumnName(FKColumnName)`. `FKColumnName` is the desired name, but `FKPropertyName` should either be known or explicitly set with `HasForeignKey` as in the second example. This could be avoided in both cases by extracting it from (and actually setting it with) the EF Core metadata API, e.g.

```cs
var foreignKey = withEntity.HasOne(e => e.UOM).WithMany().Metadata;
// with metadata API
foreignKey.Properties[0].SetColumnName("WithEntityValueUOMId");
// or if you prefer fluent API, even though I see no benefit of using it in this particular case
withEntity.Property(foreignKey.Properties[0].Name).HasColumnName("WithEntityValueUOMId");
```